# Problemas con Visual Studio y MASM

Tags: visual-studio, masm

Estoy implementado unos ejemplos del libro Moderm x86 Assembly Language, que suelen hacer uso de un  programa en C++ y otro en assembler,
y me estoy encontrando con una situación que no acabo de "comprender".
¿Cuando me aparece o no, la opción de Microsoft Macro Assembler en la ventana
de propiedades del programa en ASM?.

Tengo claro, que para que me aparezca esta propiedad tengo que activar, antes,
la opción MASM en Build Dependencies > Build costumization > y ya aquí, activar la opción
**masm(.targets, .props)**. Lo he leído en repetidas respuestas sobre este tema.

La segunda recomendación, también expuesta en las respuestas, es que el programa
debe de tener la extensión .asm.

Hasta aquí, todo claro.

Si la secuencia que sigo es:

```
Nuevo proyecto, 
Activar MASM en Build dependencies,
Añadir el programa fuente.asm,
```

me aparece la opción **Microsoft Macro Assembler** en
la ventana de la propiedades de **source_.asm**.
Después añado el programa en C++, source.cpp, y todo parece encajar. Ningún problema.

La situación se me descontrola, si la secuencia es,

```
Nuevo proyecto, 
Add el programa en C++,
Build costumization, etc.
Add el programa en ensamblador.
```

Tengo observado, que cuando sigo la secuencia:
**Nuevo proyecto**, **add fuente C++**, **salvar fuente**,
**Build propierties** > **Build costumization** en la ventana que me presenta, **ya me aparece activada la opción MASM**. En estos casos, tengo también observado, que cuando creo el programa en assembler, y voy a la ventana de **Source_.asm Property Pages**, no me aparece **Microsoft Macro Assembler**,
sino, en General, **Item type Does not participate in build**.

Si desactivo la opción MASM, y salvo, cuando vuelvo a seguir la secuencia Build propierties, etc, la **opción MASM vuelve a aparecer activada**, a pesar de que la desactivé.

Tengo claro que siguiendo el primer procedimiento, todo parece encajar correctamente, pero si con el proyecto
avanzado tuviese que incluir un programa en ensamblador, ¿Cual sería en procedimiento a seguir?, ya que
el añadir a posteriori el programa en ensamblador, a mi no me parece funcionar.

Algo se me está escapando. ¿Qué es?
[image: Captura de la pantalla de propiedades del programa en ensamblador]

Añado captura de pantalla con todas las opciones que me presenta **Item type**

[image: Captura pantalla de Item type]

Editado para añadir info:

En estos días, desde que publiqué la pregunta, he observado que
si cierro la solución, borro todos los ficheros que se crearon,
vuelvo a iniciar la secuencia de creación, es decir Build Dependencies, Bulid Customizations..., la opción MASM me vuelve a aparecer seleccionada, dando pie a que después no me trate correctamente el fichero .asm que crearé posteriormente, pero si cierro Visual Studio, lo vuelvo a arrancar, repito la secuencia de creación, si me aparece vacía la opción MASM. ¡Curioso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que se está tratando de un error introducido en la versión 2022 de Visual Studio.

Editado, según sugerencia de @Israel-ICM.

Según el soporte de Visual Studio, existe ya una corrección disponible en la versión [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5 Preview 3](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) del mismo.
Yo he comprobado que esa versión corrige el problema.
La última versión oficial, al día de hoy, 18FEB23, VS Community 17.4.5, todavía no incluye la corrección.

Si a alguien le interesa detalles de la solución puede encontrarla en [Build customization menu broken in VS2022](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-customization-menu-broken-in-VS202/10226457)

**Editado**, de nuevo, el **22FEB23**:

**Problema corregido** definitivamente en la versión 17.5.0

Comment: Saludos @Chemag, las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad puesto que estas mismas podrían desaparecer a futuro convirtiéndose en enlaces muertos, por lo mismo es necesario que se agreguen las partes importantes de éste y simplemente luego dejas el enlace como referencia.

Comment: @Israel-ICM Sigo tu recomendación. Gracias